# Traget already exist STM32CUBEIDE

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

[image]
I get this error every Time i try to generate the code from the config .ioc file

Answer (score 0):

Go to **C:\Users<USER>\STM32Cube\Repository** and extract **stm32cube_fw_l0_v1121.zip** manually. Or remove zip file, FW folder and generate again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but i did your solutions and i still get the same errors

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I did the config of the device config tool in that way and it worked.